# Error when changing the color of a div with on hover and Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

[http://codepen.io/Feners4/pen/KggAwg](http://Cube%20Code%20Pen)

I've been trying to get this cube I created and make it change color on mouse hover with Angular. For testing purposes, I started with changing the color of just on side of the cube. However, I keep getting this error on the console:

> Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

My Html is:

```
 <header>
      Angularity
    </header>

    <h1>hjskl</hi>

    <body>
      <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
                </div>
      </header>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="cube">
            <div ng-app="App" class="front" change-background colorcode=¨#FE0883¨></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
            <div class="top"></div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My JS is:

```
angular.module('App', ['appf'])
  .directive('changeBackground', ['$animate', function($animate) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        colorcode: '@?'
      },
      link: function($scope, element, attr) {
        element.on('mouseenter', function() {
          element.addClass('change-color');
          element.css('background-color', $scope.colorcode);
        });
        element.on('mouseleave', function() {
          element.removeClass('change-color');
          element.css('background-color', '#fff');
        });
      }
    };
  }])
```

How can I fix this error in my code? Does it have to do with the placement of the ng-app in my html?

Comment: Why not just plain css:hover

Comment: I'm want to do this with just Angular so I can learn how to do this type of thing through it.. @Darkrum

Comment: Do you have this module `'appf'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
angular.module('App', ['appf'])
```

to

```
angular.module('App', [])
```

seemed to work.  'appf' appears to be a dependency that the module cannot find.